# Downloading files raw.githubusercontent.com is immensely slow

Tags: python, github, github-api

I'm building an application in python 3 that requires downloading a whole bunch of *.java files from raw.githubusercontent.com. Basically, I use the GitHub's API v3 to obtain the all paths ending with ".java" in a given repository, then I download them through raw.githubusercontent.com. The trouble is that this is really slow (< 10 kB/s). Now sometimes, it starts of at a decent rate (40-50 kB/s), but then it usually drops of pretty quickly.

I've tried keeping a persistent connection by using requests.Session(). I've also tried using an authorization token, which someone suggested. Both of these failed to give an improvement.

This is how my code looks like:

```
with requests.Session() as s:
    path_index = ""
    for path in paths.splitlines():
        file_url = githubusercontent_prefix + path
        filename = path.split("/")[-1]
        res = s.get(file_url, stream=True, allow_redirects=True)
        outf = open("sources/" + filename, 'w')
        outf.write(res.text)
        outf.close()
```

Comment: Consider using a Python Git library to pull the files from your repo instead of getting the files from githubusercontent.com.

Comment: @AdilB That's basically what I ended up doing. I did some experimenting with wget and I noticed that if you tried to download the same set of files twice, the second time it would be much much faster. So githubusercontent.com probably does some sort of caching of files. Just using "git clone" ended up being much faster, even when only a small part of it consists of *.java files.

Comment: Awesome - yeah, I figured using a git library would make the most sense, since that's GitHub's main purpose :)